# Unable to insert value to mysql database using spring boo

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

[image]

> Hibernate: insert into employee (age, name) values (?, ?)

I don't know how to fix it and i try all method but till i get this error.
how to solve it and i search in google, stack overflow but i didn't find the exact solution.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: Hello Sandy, for now we can't see any error. The line starting with `Hibernate:` on the console could be just a log of the SQL statement. If you get an exception then please provide the full stack trace (as code block, not an image) and more details on when it happend? what function did you used for testing? etc.

Comment: If possible give the error if any as text and not as image.  The image you provided does not show any error.

Answer (score 0):

> insert into employee (age, name) values (?, ?)

is not an error, it's a log telling you that insert happened.

due to this line in properties `spring.jpa.show-sql = true`

if you want to remove it for some reason just set show-sql to false or remove that line